# Is there a way to estimate the write bandwidth from java to an Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

We have a large volume of data and want to know how fast it can be written to Oracle.
Is there a way to estimate the write bandwidth from java to an Oracle DB? We can use any approach (not necessarily JDBC) if it is faster. For example it would be useful to know for X disk speed, Y processor, then you can write Z bytes/second. Is there a way to estimate such a data rate?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we find out what you're trying to do? For example, if you are going to be loading tables SQL*LOADER will be faster as it can run directly on the DB.  Can you define the problem better ?

Comment: Yes - we have 100's of MB of numerical data calculated by a java process; trying to find roughly how long that will take to write to Oracle, say on an average modern server (likely windows). If no formula is possible then any rule of thumb would be interesting - thanks!

Comment: It depends hugely on the structure of the tables/indexes. Will you be loading these into new tables or updating existing data? Is it just a set of rows or do you need to load into several interrelated tables. Etc.

Comment: Our target structure (as yet not clearly defined as not yet sure whether to try to write all this to Oracle!) would be OLAP-like, so likely one data table with several linked dimension tables. For each data result I would expect one insert to the data table, and potential inserts to the dimensions tables for new items [sorry that's all a bit abstract:-)].

Comment: Can you overlap your generation and loading, or do you have to wait until all the data is generated before loading it?

Comment: That's also worth considering - appreciate all the input. Think the answer may be to do some testing - thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any standard formula. Among other things it also depends on your schema  (e.g whether you have indexes on the tables), the file system, how many disks you have, the RAID level you are using, how the tables, indexes, logs etc are spread out across those disks...

Try it and see is probably the only way.

If there is a way of estimating it given all that, I'd like to know about it too!

Comment: +1 The magic formula you're looking for doesn't exist. The only way to get a decent idea is to do some proper testing.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with Paul and Qwerky.  You can however break the task up (if possible).  Can you write the results to disk first (that gives the time to generate w/ io) and then load the results into the db (oracle time).  Now once you have a consistent data set, you can tweek the oracle stuff and measure it on different configurations.

Comment: Certainly could split up like that - so it would be faster to write to a disk file then import that to Oracle than write directly? Thanks!

Comment: I think @Jim's not saying it's faster - just that starting with a disk file means you can test various loading options without the generation time potentially confusing things.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the network bandwidth, processor speed and disk write bandwidth, you need to know how much Oracle will inflate the size of the packets and how much it will inflate the data when it write them to disk. (i.e. what is the overhead) This depends entirely on your data structure, but for a given dtata structure it will be the same. Without more information I would guess its is a factor of 2-3.

I would suggest the total time is the sum of the combined delays. (Unless you know differently, concurrency is possible but unlikely ;)  You can guestimate how long each part of the process takes and it could be accurate to within a factor of three.  This doesn't replace testing in any way but if your test time is significantly different it is worth checking why.

A formula might look like the following assuming you have large transactions (not trying to commit each record individually)

Network delay - 100 MB over 1 Gb link with 100% overhead takes 2 seconds.

Processor delay - 100 MB with 200% overhead on a processor which can move 300 MB/s takes 1 second

Disk delay - 100 MB with 200% overhead to disks which can sustain 60 MB/s takes 5 seconds.

Note: depending on how you cache you data write through/write back the data to disk could be almost entirely cached and written out later.

This results in a guess of 3 - 8 seconds.

However, you would still need to test your specific system to find out how long this takes.

Comment: That's not the question, though.  The OP is asking whether there is a formula for write bandwidth given those things. Not asking how to calculate network bandwisth etc.